# Scp the Three Newest Files Using Bash

Tags: bash, scp

I'm trying to scp the three newest files in a directory. Right now I use `ls -t | head -3` to find out their names and just write them out in the scp command, but this becomes arduous. I tried using `ls -t | head -3 | scp *username*@*address*:*path*` but this didn't work. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

perhaps the simplest solution, but it does not deal with spaces in filenames

```
scp `ls -t | head -3` user@server:.
```

using xargs has the advantage of dealing with spaces in file names, but will execute scp three times

```
ls -t | head -3 | xargs -i scp {} user@server:.
```

a loop based solution would look like this.  We use while read here because the default delimiter for read is the newline character not the space character like the for loop

```
ls -t | head -3 | while read file ; do scp $file user@server ; done
```

saddly, the perfect solution, one which executes a single scp command while working nicely with white space, eludes  me at the moment.

Comment: Same as other answer it will also send only 1 file if first 2 entries of are NOT files.

Comment: I do not believe that the poster ever listed in his requirements that he needed to deal with directories.  In fact the way that he has been doing it implies that he does not.

Comment: interesting use of the -i/{} xarg option. Will that result in only 1 call to scp, rather than the 3 calls we would expect from a for-loop based solution?

Comment: Sadly, no.  This solution basically implements the loop.  It is just faster to type and can deal with white space.  Let me think about it for a second the should be a way to make it execute as one command.  It will just likely be more typing;-)

Comment: Fortunately, I never put spaces in my file names, so your first solution should work great. Thanks! This is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Write a simple bash script. This one will send the last three files as long as they are a file and not a directory.

#!/bin/bash

```
DIR=`/bin/pwd`

for file in `ls -t ${DIR} | head -3`:
 do
  if [ -f ${file} ];
  then
    scp ${file} user@host:destinationDirectory
  fi
done
```

Comment: It will send only 1 file if first 2 entries of are NOT files.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script to scp latest 3 files from supplied 1st argument path to this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$1"

for f in $(ls -t `find ${DIR} -maxdepth 1 -type f` | head -3)
 do
    scp ${f} user@host:destinationDirectory
done
```

`find -type f` makes sure only files are found in ${DIR} and `head -3` takes top 3 files.

Comment: This solution will fail if there is a space in a file name.  You should use read.

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't relevant anymore for the poster, but you brought me to an idea which I think is what you want:

```
tar cf - `ls -t | head -3` | ssh *username*@*server* tar xf - -C *path*
```

Comment: That's a clever use of tar. I'll have to give that a try the next time I need to use this command. Thanks for posting!